# ACCESS query update trouble

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a table like this:
[image]

Then I created a query that give me SumOfAmount per Code and IBAN. A result of the query:

[image]

This is the query I used:

```
SELECT Tabella.CODE, Tabella.IBAN, Sum(Tabella.AMOUNT) AS SumOfAMOUNT FROM Tabella GROUP BY Tabella.CODE, Tabella.IBAN;
```

Now I'm trying to write in the column "SUMAMOUNT" of the table the sum of amount per "CODE" and "IBAN" but i can't reach this.

I'd want something like this:

[image]

Can you help me? I'm using MS ACCESS. 
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a correlated subquery:

```
select t.*,
       (select sum(t2.amount)
        from tabella as t2
        where t2.code = t.code and t2.iban = t.iban
       ) as summaount
from tabella as t;
```

EDIT:

To update the column, then use `update` with a correlated subquery:

```
update tabella
    set summacount = (select sum(t2.amount)
                      from tabella as t2
                      where t2.code = tabella.code and t2.iban = tabella.iban
                     );
```

Comment: I'll try that, but i need to do an insert into the table so that "sumamount" column is updated... how can i reach this?